# How can i make a field read only when i selected a picklist value

Tags: record-type, configuration

This article was old one but I want to know step by step. Consider there is picklist status in case object. When I add extra picklist values to status, It should be visible to only particular users. How can I do this. could any one help me out for this issue.

Comment: Which article? You mention an article, but forgot the link.

Comment: Hi peter please find the below link

Comment: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gilKAAQ

Comment: See my answer below. It is still record types you want to use, but you don't need separate page layouts, just the record type picklist filter. The online help for this is pretty good and you should find the step-by-step you want in there. If you have specific problems making it work, be sure to ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

In standard point-and-click configuration the way you allow one user to see some picklist values and another to see different ones is with record types. You then set the record type accessibility to be exclusive for each user's profile.

From the [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_recordtype.htm&language=en_US):

> Record types allow you to offer different business processes, picklist values, and page layouts to different users.
>
> ...
>
> Create record types for opportunities to differentiate your regular sales deals from your professional services engagements and offer different picklist values for each.

You can also make it so that for one user with one profile, the record type allows you to assign a different page layout.

This is pretty quick and easy to do, so if you can get these to work for you, go for it. Record types work for most standard objects and all custom objects, but check the considerations section in the link I put above.

If you can make it work, the step-by-step instructions for creating and modifying record types are shown in the links in the docs above.

After record types it is a huge cliff to fall off to implement in Visualforce and Apex. But this requires basically re-implementing your entire edit page in Visualforce, just to write some filter logic into the picklist you want.